# Struct and Link List Question

Tags: c, visual-c++

I just learned how to use linked lists in C. Everything is okay if I use a single struct, but I am having problems when I use two structures to separate the data properly. I am having problems allocating. I am using Visual C++ Express 2010, and here's the entire code. Anyone could explain to me what went wrong? Thanks a lot. And this isn't homework. I am just trying to learn it further.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student 
{
    char name[20];
    int num;

};

struct Node
{
    struct Student data;
    struct Node *next;
};


//void initList(struct Student **);
struct Node *createNode(struct Student );
void append(struct Node **, struct Student);
void traverse(struct Node *);
void destroyList(struct Node *);
int main()
{
    char choice = 'y';
    struct Student dat;
    struct Node *head;
    head = NULL;
    //struct Student *tmp;
    //initList(&head);
    char buff[20];
    while(choice != 'n')
    {
        scanf("%s %d", buff, &dat.num);
        strcpy(dat.name, buff);
        append(&head, dat);


        printf("\n\nWould you like to enter another?");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }

    traverse(head);
    destroyList(head);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
/*
void initList(struct Student **list)
{
    *list = NULL;
}
*/
struct Node *createNode(struct Student dat)
{
    struct Node *temp;
    temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = dat;

    return temp;
}

void append(struct Node **pos, struct Student d)
{
    struct Node *node;
    node = createNode(d);

    if(*pos == NULL)
    {
        *pos = node;
    }
    else
    {
        struct Node *tmp;
        tmp = *pos;
        while(tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = node;

    }
}

void traverse(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *tmp;
    for(tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        printf("\n %s %d\n\n", tmp->data.name, tmp->data.num);
    }

}
void destroyList(struct Node *list)
{
    if(list->next == NULL)
    {
        free(list);
    }
    else
    {
        destroyList(list->next);
        free(list);
    }
    printf("\n\nList has been destroyed.\n");
}
```

Comment: Woah.  Please format your code.

Comment: sorry, was about to do so hehe.

Comment: pmg, i copy pasted it from my ide of course. sorry if I pasted it too soon.

Comment: What does "I am having problems allocating" mean? Does your code fail to compile? Crash? Run out of memory? Produce wrong-looking output? What exactly (1) did you hope would happen and (2) actually happened?

Comment: Gareth, it's giving me an error message at runtime saying access to a specific memory location is denied. something like that. doesn't appear until I enter info for the third node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `createNode()` you should set the `next` member to NULL; or even in `append()` if it makes you feel better :)

Comment: what i want to know is that when I use a single struct for the list, it works using the same functions with little alterations. After creating the Student struct to separate the "data" and altering user input, it's giving me errors at runtime. :(

Comment: Can you identify the function where the errors happen? At first glance I see no reason for errors